# From address is hostname.domain

Tags: postfix-mta

I followed this guide to setup a POSTFIX webserver https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-postfix-e-mail-server-with-dovecot.

From there, I used these settings:

```
myhostname = mail.domain.com
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mail.domain.com, domain.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
```

It works fine, except the mail command sends emails from user@hostname.domain, rather than user@domain.  Obviously, those emails can then not be replied too.  Is this a setting in POSTFIX that I can change?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter that you are looking for is `myorigin`. Change file `/etc/mailname` would change the sender address. See http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#myorigin